# Least Common Denominator: $ \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x}+\frac{\ln\ x}{2\sqrt{x}} $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, rationalising-denominator

$$ \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x}+\frac{\ln \ x}{2\sqrt{x}} $$

I have tried combining these two fractions; however, I keep getting stuck.

$$\frac{2\sqrt{x}}{2\sqrt{x}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x}+\frac{\ln\ x}{2\sqrt{x}}\cdot \frac{x}{x}$$

So that we get

$$\frac {2x}{2\sqrt{x}\cdot(x)}+\frac {x\ln\ x}{2\sqrt{x}\cdot(x)}$$

What am I doing wrong? The answer is $$ \frac{2+\ln\ x}{2\sqrt{x}}$$

Comment: The key here is that $\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}.$

Comment: Also, $\ln x \cdot x \neq \ln x^2$

Comment: $ \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x}+\frac{\ln \ x}{2\sqrt{x}} =\frac{2\sqrt{x}\sqrt{x}+x\ln x}{2x\sqrt{x}}=\frac{2x+x\ln x}{2x\sqrt{x}}=\frac{2+\ln x}{2\sqrt{x}}$

Comment: Zoil - you factored out the x*s and then cancelled them out with one in the denominator? Also, why are you not allowed to multiply the x into the natural logarithm? Is there a special rule?

Comment: $y\ln x=\ln(x^y)$ and not $\ln(y\times x)$.

Comment: Do you want to create an answer? I will select it. Nonetheless, thanks.

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Comment: Hint: $\ \color{#c00}{x = \sqrt{x}^{\,\large 2}}\ $ so $\, \dfrac{\sqrt x}{\color{#c00}x} = \dfrac{\sqrt x}{\color{#c00}{\sqrt{x}^{\,\large 2}}} = \,\ldots\  $ by cancelling $\,\sqrt x\ \ $

Answer (score 1):

The square root $\sqrt{x}$ seems to be the thing that bothers you: pretend it's not there! That is, write temporarily $\sqrt{x}=z$ so that $x=z^2$; then
$$
\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x}+\frac{\ln x}{2\sqrt{x}}
=
\frac{z}{z^2}+\frac{\ln(z^2)}{2z}
$$
Now, for avoiding misunderstandings, write temporarily $\ln(z^2)=\ln x=L$ so you have
$$
\frac{z}{z^2}+\frac{L}{2z}=\frac{1}{z}+\frac{L}{2z}=
\frac{2+L}{2z}
$$
Substitute back to reinstate $x$:
$$
\frac{2+L}{2z}=\frac{2+\ln x}{2\sqrt{x}}
$$

This is longer, but safer. With some experience, you'll recognize more easily that
$$
\frac{\sqrt{x}}{x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}
$$
but the method of temporarily renaming objects to make them simpler works in several other cases.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

Sometimes one representation is more convenient for what you're trying to do than the other is.